# Confusion in calculating probability.

Tags: probability

We are given a joint probability function as following:

$$f(X=x,Y=y) = \begin{cases} Qu\mathrm{e}^{-(Qx+uy)} &\mbox{for } x, y > 0 \\ 
0 & \mbox{otherwise}. \end{cases}$$

where $Q$ and $u$ are real constants. We are supposed to calculate $P(X>Y)$.

For this I took the double integral of the above function but the answer does not come out to be constant.Can someone please elaborate on the double integration where $x$ goes from $y$ to infinity and $y$ goes from $0$ to infinity. I hope my limits are correct.

Comment: What is "Que^(-(Qx+uy))"?

Comment: @ZeroXLR Q and u are constants and e is mathematical constant.

Comment: Ah I see. You have issues with your LaTeX case formatting. Let me see if I can fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integrating the region under the line $y=x$ you should start off with the following:$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{x}Que^{-(Qx+uy)}\,dy\,dx$$

$$Qu\int_0^{\infty}e^{-Qx}dx\int_0^xe^{-uy}dy$$

Comment: I thought order of integration does not matter.Turns out it does matter.

Comment: In this case it does because you need to express the integral on `y` as a function of `x`. If you're looking for lots of examples to work through, an older version of [Schaum's Outline of Probability](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=schaum%27s%20random%20processes%20pdf) is available online.